# Parse JSON Array Item With No Name Using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to figure out how to use JSON feeds and display them on PHP pages.  I've learned a lot using various examples but I've run into a snag with a specific situation.  Dealing with arrays that don't have specific names or IDs for each field.

For instance:

```
    {
"Team1": [
    "2869",
    "4039817.99"
],
"Team2": [
    "66",
    "113980.00"
],
"Team3": [
    "3408",
    "4671603.22"
]
    }
```

Now, I only want to retrieve the second number in each of those arrays, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I've tried using this script to display it in a table but every iteration of this I try, it doesn't seem to work:

```
     <script>
     var dmJSON = "http://...";
     var completeurl = dmJSON; 

     $.getJSON( completeurl, function(data) {
     $.each(data.objects, function(i, f) {
     var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>Team 1</td>" + "<td>" + f.Team1.1 + "</td>" + </tr>"
     $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
     });

     });
       </script>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access arrays with the `[]` syntax:

```
f.Team1[1]
```

Comment: I had the wrong times mixed up on that first comment, but you rock!

Answer (score 0):

`f.Team.1` tries to access the property `1` of `f.Team`. Since `f.Team` doesn't have a property `1` it will fail. Instead, you probably intended index `1` for which the syntax is `f.Team[1]`.

Also, property names can not start with a digits so `f.Team.1` gives a syntax error.

Keep in mind that Arrays are Objects in JavaScript. This is completely valid:

```
var a = [];
a.foo = "bar";
a[0] = "baz";
a.length; // 1, not 2!
```